# DBLink in PostgreSQL drops DNS name of target (Redshift), but recovers after service restart

Tags: postgresql, sockets, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, postgresql-9.3

I've a (random) problem within PG 9.3.

I have stored procedures, that create a dblink connection to a redshift instance.

It used to work fine, but recently it stopped.

Setup:

1. AWS EC2 instance (ubuntu) with PostgreSQL 9.3 installed
2. AWS Redshift as the target

Query:

```
    SELECT dblink_connect('host=xxx.redshift.amazonaws.com port=5432 dbname=xxx user=xxx password=xxx');
    [Other commands]
    SELECT dblink_disconnect();
```

It works on one day. 
The next day, I get the following error

> ERROR:  could not establish connection
>   DETAIL:  could not translate host name "xxx.redshift.amazonaws.com" to address: Name or service not known

But it works via IP. 
And it works via the name, if I run psql via the command line

```
    psql -h xxx.redshift.amazonaws.com port=5432 -d xxx -U xxx
```

As soon as I restart the postgresql service, it's fine again.

The postgresql log has no errors in it.
From what I can see, there are no connections left open after the procedures finish.
The syslog shows some lines, a couple of hours after the last query, where I'm not sure if they could be related/where they're coming from:

> Mar 22 22:37:55 ip-xxx upstart-udev-bridge[16120]: Disconnected from Upstart
>
> Mar 22 22:37:55 ip-xxx upstart-socket-bridge[16123]: Disconnected from Upstart
>
> Mar 22 22:37:55 ip-xxx kernel: [801531.255841] init: upstart-udev-bridge main process (16120) terminated with status 1
>
> Mar 22 22:37:55 ip-xxx kernel: [801531.255861] init: upstart-udev-bridge main process ended, respawning
>
> Mar 22 22:37:55 ip-xxx kernel: [801531.256172] init: upstart-socket-bridge main process (16123) terminated with status 1
>
> Mar 22 22:37:55 ip-xxx kernel: [801531.256185] init: upstart-socket-bridge main process ended, respawning
>
> Mar 22 22:37:55 ip-xxx kernel: [801531.256399] init: upstart-file-bridge main process (16126) terminated with status 1
>
> Mar 22 22:37:55 ip-xxx kernel: [801531.256413] init: upstart-file-bridge main process ended, respawning

Comment: seems that it was related to a recent update of the libc6:amd64 (2.19-0ubuntu6.10) package, that contained an issue. this was installed automatically yesterday. i will verify it. found also https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74287

Comment: version 2.19-0ubuntu6.11 fixed it. the log messages that i posted, were linked to unattended upgrades and there i found the libc6 upgrade.